# CSS Ribbon - How to make a transparent triangle while disregarding background

Tags: css, sass

I have an ribbon overlay over an image. 
The right side of the ribbon should contain a triangle.

I have been able to create the triangle via pseudo elements but can't figure out how to set the colors to disregard the parent's background color.

Currently, I've set it to white to show that there's a shape drawn, but I was hoping to set the white to transparent.

[Codepen attempt here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXMLEM)

```
.homefeed-img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 458px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.homefeed-img {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.home-img-time-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;

  &:before, &:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 45px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
  }

  &:before {
    border-top: solid 22.5px transparent;
    border-right: solid 20px #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 22.5px transparent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to make the border-color transparent, but I changed the way to create the triangle. I added another div inside the wrapper as a triangle and position it how it fits. Check the codepen script to see the result.

http://codepen.io/LevelZwo/pen/bepPvd

HTML:

```
<div class="home-img-time-overlay"> 
   2 minutes ago
   <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home-img-time-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 20px 0 0;
  border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can make border transparent. It will always take the color of the main object behind.

I would suggest making the border color similiar to the background image.

```
border-right: solid 20px #998485;
```